# WSO2 Identity Server 6.1 - Unable to compile class for JSP

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I compiled the platform from source code and it started working.
Thanks to Anuradha of WSO2 for her guidance on fixing the bug with JDK.

I still see one more error in the log. This time with compiling the JSP. The log:

```
[2023-08-03 16:57:33,988] [] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/authenticationendpoint]} - Servlet [dynamic_prompt.do] in web application [/authenticationendpoint] threw load() exception org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [18] in the generated java file: [/usr/lib/wso2/wso2is/6.1.0/lib/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/authenticationendpoint/org/apache/jsp/dynamic_005fprompt_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.util.TemplateMgtAPIClient resolves to a package

Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:213)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:498)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:397)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:367)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:351)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:605)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:399)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.init(JspServlet.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1010)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5264)
```

I could not get to the bottom of this error to fix it.

I compiled from source and deployed the product. I am expecting the help in resolving the above issue.

Comment: Do you get this error just after starting the server or else when trying to log in to console/ some other application?

Comment: While starting the server. Even after this error, the server starts. However, I am able to open the carbon console and other apps are working.

Comment: i am facing similar issue in login.jsp just by running the tutorial sample: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/mfa/username-and-password/#! (IS latest version)